# I am having an Insert into error with my query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-insert, executenonquery

I am trying to insert data into an Access database table using an insert query, I get the error Syntax error in `INSERT INTO` statement.

I have even tried the sql string without parameters and get the same error but if I paste the same query straight into Access it works.

```
Dim sqlinsert As String
'sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO JobApplicants(Title, Address, Postcode, Phone, Email, Position, Education) VALUES(@Title, @Address, @Postcode, @Phone, @Email, @Position, @Education)"
' sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO JobApplicants(Title, ApplicantName,Address, Postcode, Phone, Email, Position, Education) VALUES('" & comboTitle.Text.ToString & "','" & txtApplicantName.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtPostcode.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "','" & comboPosition.Text & "','" & comboEducation.Text & "')"
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO JobApplicants(Title, ApplicantName,Address, Postcode, Phone, Email, Position, Education) VALUES('Mr','freed','12 high st','sa123er','01234567890','a@b.c','head','gcse')"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con1)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Title", comboTitle.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Address", txtAddress.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Postcode", txtPostcode.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Phone", txtPhone.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Position", comboPosition.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Education", comboEducation.Text))

con1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con1.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POSITION` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-AE9D9ADA-3255-4B12-91A9-F855BDD9C5A2) in Access.

So you have to use square brackets in the query.

```
"INSERT INTO JobApplicants(Title, ApplicantName, Address, Postcode, Phone, Email, [Position], ..."
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was driving me crazy.  So simple when you know.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding 7 parameters to a prepared statement which doesn't actually have any placeholders.  The insert statement, as raw SQL, happens to be valid, but I suspect binding parameters which do not exist in the statement is the source of the error.  So, try using placeholders in the prepared statement:

```
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO JobApplicants (Title, ApplicantName,Address, Postcode, Phone, Email, [Position], Education) VALUES (@Title, @ApplicantName, @Address, @Postcode, @Phone, @Email, @Position, @Education)"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con1)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Title", comboTitle.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ApplicantName", txtApplicant.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Address", txtAddress.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Postcode", txtPostcode.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Phone", txtPhone.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Position", comboPosition.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Education", comboEducation.Text))

con1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con1.Close()
```

Note that you don't actually bind a value for the applicant's name.  Therefore, I am assuming that there is a text box somewhere called `txtApplicant`, whose text property we can access to get that value.

Comment: Sorry I edited out lots of code to show just the bare bones of the issue and accidently removed "cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ApplicantName", txtApplicantName.Text))" so that was not the issue, as described below it was position being a reserved word, once I put it in square brackets everything was good.

Answer (score 0):

## use bracket

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO MCAscheduled **([URno],[SName],[hsc],[gper],[pgper],[pstatus],[cname],[hrname],[position],[hscinter],[ginter],[pginter],[comments])"** + "VALUES (" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ",'" & txtName.Text & "'," & CInt(txt12Per.Text) & "," & CInt(txtGPer.Text) & "," & CInt(TextBox1.Text) & ",'" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & ComboBox4.Text & "'," & CInt(TextBox12.Text) & "," & CInt(TextBox11.Text) & "," & CInt(TextBox10.Text) & ",'" & TextBox9.Text & "');"
```

Comment: No! Always use Parameters to avoid Sql Injection. Never concatenate strings. Suppose a user enters ";Drop Table MCAscheduled;" into one of those text boxes?